# Orthogonal diagonalization and relationship between the eigenvectors of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the orthogonal diagonalization of $$A =  \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 4\\\end {bmatrix}.$$
How's the relationship between the eigenvectors of the matrix A? Explain and prove it!

Attempt:
I understand how to find the orthogonal diagonalization, with D of this problem is $$D =  \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 8\\\end {bmatrix}  $$
(Please check, is that even right?)
However, I don't understand the question below it, how's the relationship between the eigenvectors? So far, I have only come up with one answer: "that they are orthogonal." But I can't seem to find a more thorough explanation. Can you help me?

Comment: If the matrix $P$ in $P^{-1}AP=D$ is just nonsingular, then your eigenvectors have to be linearly independent. If $P$ is orthogonal, eigenvectors have to be mutually orthonormal (not just orthogonal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the eigenvalues are $2,2,8$.

It is not entirely correct to say "the eigenvectors are orthogonal". Because $A$ is symmetric, eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues will be orthogonal. The eigenvalue $2$, though, has a $2$-dimensional eigenspace, so many eigenvectors will not be "orthogonal".

Comment: So how should I answer the question with a thorough explanation?